# C build string as recursivelly traversing binary tree

Tags: c, string, recursion, binary-tree

I have the following situation where I need to add an element to a binary tree and, once the condition to add it is met, I also return a string which is a binary representation of where in the tree I am adding the element.

This representation is then using the format "001101" and "0" means left, while "1" means right. E.g.:

Adding an element C in a tree in the following position:

```
        A
       /
      /
     B
      \
       \
        \
    <ADD HERE>
```

...would return a "01" string.

As this tree grows, we would have strings like "00000111101" or even larger. The method to add this element is of recursive behaviour, as it traverses the left/right children pointers and builds this binary string as it goes down into the tree.

My question is, how do I build this string recursively?

ATTEMPT 1:I've modified the method signature from:

```
void tree_insert(node **tree, node **parent, unsigned char val);
```

To:

```
void tree_insert(node **tree, node **parent, unsigned char val, char *position);
```

And then called the method sending an initial empty string "" as per the follows:

```
tree_insert(tree, NULL, val, "");
```

Then traversing:

```
if ((*tree)->left != NULL)
    tree_insert(&(*tree)->left, &(*tree), val, strcat(position, "0"));
if ((*tree)->right != NULL)
    tree_insert(&(*tree)->right, &(*tree), val, strcat(position, "1"));
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You must not modify string literal, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for this! How would you suggest for me to generate that string recursivelly?

Comment: Do you have a working insertion routine without building the string?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying string literals has undefined behaviour. Unfortunately what you want to do is not that simple to do efficiently in standard C. I'd do a buffer handling solution for C, having something like:

```
struct stringbuffer {
    size_t allocated;
    size_t length;
    char *string;
};

void init_buffer(struct stringbuffer *b) {
     b->allocated = 16;
     b->length = 0;
     b->string = malloc(16);
}

void append_char(struct stringbuffer *b, char c) {
    if (b->length + 2 > b->allocated) {
        b->string = realloc(b->string, b->allocated * 2);
    }
    b->string[b->length ++] = c;
    b->string[b->length] = 0;
}
```

Then:

```
struct stringbuffer buffer;
init_buffer(buffer);

recursive_algorithm(&buffer);
... 
append_char(b, '0')
append_char(b, '1')
```

---

However if you're lucky enough to use *POSIX* then you can probably use [`open_memstream`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream) to create a `FILE *` that you can even `fprintf` to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *buffer;
    size_t size;
    FILE *f = open_memstream(&buffer, &size);
    fprintf(f, "0");
    fputc('1', f);
    fclose(f);
    buffer[size] = 0;
    puts(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am not sure I understand still. The problem is that I probably need a buffer for each leaf as I go down the tree? I need to maintain all those strings until one of the recursive paths actually returns with the correct string.

Comment: No, you're building 1 string as you go down.

Comment: I don't believe so. Since I am inserting an element recursively,  it starts at the root, and if this is not the correct place for insertion, it then creates 2 branches one for the left node and another for the right node. Note that, at this second level of recursion, it does the same thing again - making a total of 4 branches. At this point, each branch will have its own string, namely "00", "01", "10" and "11". This will go on until one of multiple strings then will be representing the exact point where the value was added (e.g.: "011101101").

Comment: You need to either call your function with a pre-allocated buffer large enough to hold the result string (you must know how large is large enough), or grow the buffer as you go. The first part of the answer is concerned with a buffer that can grow. It's a tad more complicated than a simple pointer to a character array, as it must know its own size, and how much of it is already filled.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure why you even use a binary tree if you have to traverse to *every* node to find a place for insertion.